# How do you create (automatically inserted) LaTeX template with Emacs+AUCTeX?

Tags: templates, emacs, latex, auctex

I use Emacs+AUCTex for writing LaTeX documents. I have specific needs so my typical preamble is quite long. Today, I have a .tex file with only this preamble (a template so) and I use C-x C-w to write a new file from this template. It isn't the best solution because my template localization could be far away from the new file.

So is there a way to call LaTeX templates in Emacs in another (shorter) way?

EDIT : auto-insert-mode offers a way to achieve what I want but it doesn't put *automatically* my template (LaTeX preamble) when I create a .tex file. I have to launch M-x auto-insert. How can I automatize this based on the file extension?

Comment: I [wrote a patch](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.devel/3084) to add templates in AUCTeX but there wasn't a follow-up.

Comment: I recommend a form file directory of templates, and call up whatever you need and use it, or insert it into whatever you have already.  You could also use YASnippet for that purpose.  As @juanleon, suggested the function you want is `insert-file`.  If using OSX, then `insert-file-from-osx-panel` is available if Emacs was built `--with-ns`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of `VirTeX-common-initialization` (essentially) `TeX-master-file` is added to `find-file-hooks`. This is the source for the `%%% Local Variables: %%% mode: latex %%% TeX-master: t %%% End:` stuff. (Note, that `VirTeX-common-initialization` is the first thing in `LaTeX-common-initialization` which is called in `TeX-latex-mode` being an alias for `latex-mode`.)

To get ride of the automagically added comments you can remove the hook:

```
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (remove-hook 'find-file-hooks (car find-file-hooks) 'local)))
```

That looks like a hack. But adding `TeX-master-file` is quite hard-coded without user-options. So, it seems to me that you have no other chance.

After that correction the `auto-insert` stuff works automagically.
(At least for me.)

But, I have replaced the entries in `auto-insert-alist`. Meaning, instead of

`(define-auto-insert "\\.tex$" "my-latex-template.tex")`

I have something like that:

```
(let ((el (assoc 'latex-mode auto-insert-alist)))
  (if el
      (setcdr el "/c/temp/autoinsert.tex")
    (define-auto-insert "\\.tex$" "/c/temp/autoinsert.tex")))
```

Maybe, that is important, maybe not. I've got to get home now and I cannot further investigate that.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. The key idea is to delete what was automatically inserted and then put the code for the template.

Comment: Note : I use the code of @Thomas (below) and it works like this.

Comment: Okay, then `auto-insert` knows its job. Thanks for the info. The comments generated by `VirTeX-common-initialization` should be optional. (But, I do not know how much auctex depends on those comments.) This would be worth a note to the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [auto-insert-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/Autoinserting.html). This is orthogonal to AUCTeX - for instance, I use it to insert a class-template for .java files.

Put the following in your `.emacs` file:

```lisp
(auto-insert-mode)
 ;; *NOTE* Trailing slash important
(setq auto-insert-directory "/path/to/template/directory/")
(setq auto-insert-query nil)
(define-auto-insert "\\.tex$" "my-latex-template.tex")
```

Of course, you could make the regular expression used as the first argument to `define-auto-insert` more complex e.g. to insert different preambles depending on the working directory.

I adapted this code from an example from the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) where you can also find additional information.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. `M-x auto-insert` works fine but not the automatic part which insert my preamble when I create a .tex file. When I use `C-x C-f` test.tex I just have `%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:`

Comment: @ppr I edited my answers because auto-insert-mode provides a more standard way to insert template skeletons into new files. It works fine for me, after adjusting the name of the directory and of the template file in the above code.

Comment: Sorry @Thomas I took so long to test your new code. I personnalized `/path/to/template/directory/` and `my-latex-template.tex` but when I create a .tex file, I still have only the message `%%% Local Variables: %%% mode: latex %%% TeX-master: t %%% End:` included (and not my template). Is it working for you?

Comment: To sum up, this answer works but not for the automatic part which should insert the template as soon as I create a .tex file with emacs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
(defun insert-latex-template()
  (when (= (point-max) (point-min))
    (insert-file "/path/to/your/template/file")))

(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'insert-latex-template)
```